# How to write a condition block to check whether the selected time is in between of 5 hours of current time from the Timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker

I need a solution to Timepicker.
I added a time picker in Javascript and now user can select the time from the dropdown,
but I want to check if the user selected the time in between of 5 hours of the current time, else return false. let me share you my code.

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    setTime: new Date(),
    "minTime": "" + hour + ":" + minute + "",
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true,
    change: countneartime
});
function countneartime(){
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var output = (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
    (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/'+ d.getFullYear()  ;
    var pickup = $(".start-date").val();
    if(output == pickup){
        // write code to check condition if user selected time within 5 hours of upcoming

    }
}
```

I want to return false if user selected time is in the upcoming 5 hours of the current time. 
please help me

Comment: It will be helpful if you add a code snippet to get the exact solution.

Comment: You can subtract one `Date` object from the other and check if the result is less, or greater than 18000000 (ms == 5h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
let hour = 12,
  minute = 0;
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
  timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
  "minTime": "" + hour + ":" + minute + "",
  dynamic: true,
  dropdown: true,
  scrollbar: true,
  change: countneartime
});

function countneartime(val) {
  var selected = new Date(val);
  var fiveHoursLater = new Date(0, 0, 0, new Date().getHours() + 5, new Date().getMinutes(), new Date().getSeconds());
  console.log(fiveHoursLater.getTime() > selected.getTime());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 40px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<input class="timepicker" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d1 = new Date();
d1.setHours(d1.getHours() + 4); //upcoming 5 hours 
var d2 = new Date($(".start-date").val());
var d3 = new Date(); //current time
var d1msecs = new Date(d1).getTime(); // get milliseconds
var d2msecs = new Date(d2).getTime(); // get milliseconds
var d3msecs = new Date(d3).getTime(); // get milliseconds

if(d1msecs <= d2msecs && d2msecs >= d3msecs)
{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: ... Why do you use `new Date(d1).getTime()`? Why don't you just call `getTime` on the existing date objects?

Comment: can anyone help me out because this code is not working as i want it send me NaN in d2

Comment: @MilanParekh: What does `$(".start-date").val()` return?

Comment: @Cerbrus i added var d2 = new Date($(".timepicker").val()); and consol.log it but it return me NAN

Comment: Please answer my question, @MilanParekh: _What does `$(".start-date").val()` return?_

Comment: i checked first if start date is match with current date than we need to check time in upcoming 5 hour

Comment: @MilanParekh: __Answer the question__. That `val()` is probably something that JavaScript does not recognize as a date.